# How to understand absolute length in css?

Tags: css

As some books said, `cm` is one of css units which are absolute length and do not depend on screen's size.

So that I think it doesn't matter which browser or device I use, if I set `1cm` on an element.

For exmple, I set font-size to `1cm`, but the result of physical length seem different in Chrome and FireFox.
[image]

I  thought both of them will have same length.Why it isn’t?

Comment: using `cm` is not rec­om­mended... use `px` or `rem/em`:https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/units.en.html

Comment: Absolute length units are not recommended for use on screen, because screen sizes vary so much. However, they can be used if the output medium is known, such as for print layout.:https://www.w3schools.com/csSref/css_units.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Browsers cannot tell what the physical size of a screen is, so for rendering on screens they relate absolute units to a reference pixel. This is an implementation detail left up to the browser and, as you observed, varies.

Save absolute units for when you are working in environments with known physical outputs (such as printing on specific paper sizes). (This will almost never happen when you are working on the WWW).

Comment: cm
;One centimeter. 1cm = 96px/2.54.;

Comment: @לבנימלכה — A browser *might* assume a DPI of 96px, not all do (which is the point of the question).